# ListItem GUID doesn't shown

Tags: custom-field-types

I want to display the GUID of a ListItem in a column of a List. 
I have created a list with some fields, including a custom field to display the guid of each listitem, this field is not editable.
When you create a new listitem, this field appears at the bottom of the page.
When I press the ok button to confirm, you access in mode for display columns and the  'GUID Value' should be appear, but only when I go to edit the listitem the GUID Value appears.
Why? Could someone help me?

My customField extends the BaseFieldControl class: which method or property I can override to display the GUID value both in edit and in view mode?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this EXACT problem yesterday. From what I can determine, the elements available to the list view are a few preselected hidden fields and any fields that are in the view. Unfortunately, GUID and UniqueId are not available. I went a different route and used generate-id() to get a unique identifier for the row, however if you need the GUID you may need to use ECMA to get it.

Some references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602042(v=office.14).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754327(v=office.14).aspx

And you can throw this into your field template to get all properties available to you

```
<xsl:for-each select="$thisNode/@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> : <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I hope someone proves me wrong and can pull the data we need out. In the mean time, hope this helps.